# Multi-page flow chart using tikzset

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I am making a flowchart using `tikzpicture` and have styled various symbols using `tikzset`. The flowchart cannot fit on one page, and I want it to span across multiple pages.

Is there a way to let the flowchart cross the page boundary? If not, is there another way to write a flowchart that spans across multiple pages?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,top=2cm}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{
    startstop/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=3cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm}, process/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=3cm, text centered, minimum height=1cm}, decision/.style = {diamond, draw, text badly centered}, connector/.style={shape=signal, draw, signal to=south,text width=1cm,text height=1cm, align=center}, line/.style = {draw, -latex'}, input/.style = {trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, draw, text width=3cm, text centered, minimum height=1cm}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture} [node distance=2cm, auto]
        
        \node[startstop] (start) {Start};
        
        \node[input, below of=start] (in1) {Input};
        
        \node[process, below of=in1] (pro1) {Process 1};
        
        \node[process, below of=pro1] (pro2) {Process 2};
        
        \node[process, below of=pro2] (pro3) {Process 3};
        
        \node[decision,below of=pro3, yshift=-0.5cm] (dec1) {Decision 1};
        
        \node[process, right of=dec1, xshift=2cm] (pro4a) {Process 4a};
        
        \node[process, below of=dec1, yshift=-0.5cm] (pro4b) {Process 4b}; 
        
        \node[process, below of=pro4b] (pro5) {Process 5};
        
        \node[process, below of=pro5] (pro6) {Process 6};
        
        \node[decision, below of=pro6, yshift=-0.5cm] (dec2) {Decision 2};
        
        \node[process, right of=dec2, xshift=2cm] (pro7a) {Process 7a};
        
        \node[process, below of=dec2, yshift=-0.5cm] (pro7b) {Process 7b};
        
        \node[connector, below of=pro7b, yshift=-0.5cm] (con1) {};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make sure the connector lands on the next page, but the blocks above it stay on the previous page?

Answer (score 1):

- Flowchart produced by provided MWE can be easily fit in one page. So it is not clear, why you like to have last node ("connector) on the next page.
- MWE is unnecessarily complex. By use of `chains` and `positioning` libraries the code can be much shorter, consistent and clear.
- Your MWE is not complete. Missed are connection lines between nodes.
- Arrows in the main branch can be drawn by use of macro `join` defined in the `chains` library.
- In the case, that your flowchart is longer and in question you show only the first part of it, than you need to draw in separate figure the second part of flowchart.

**Edit:**

- To the first MWE is added the second (dumm) part of flowchart, which was not presented in question
- Deleted is the second MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin={3cm,=2cm},
            vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes}
\tikzset{
        base/.style = {draw, text width=3cm, align=center, minimum height=1cm},
   startstop/.style = {base, rounded corners}, 
     process/.style = {base}, 
    decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.3, base, inner xsep=0pt, align=flush center}, 
        line/.style = {draw, -Latex}, 
       input/.style = {trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                       trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                       base},
   connector/.style = {shape=signal,
                       signal from=north, signal to=south, signal pointer angle=120,                        base, text width=8mm, node contents={}},
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 6mm and 8mm, 
  start chain = going below,
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by line}]
\node[startstop] (start) {Start};
\node[input]   (in1) {Input};
\node[process] (pro1) {Process 1};
\node[process] (pro2) {Process 2};
\node[process] (pro3) {Process 3};
\node[decision] (dec1) {Decision 1};
\node[process] (pro4b) {Process 4b};
\node[process] (pro5) {Process 5};
\node[process] (pro6) {Process 6};
\node[decision] (dec2) {Decision 2};
\node[process] (pro7b) {Process 7b};
    \end{scope}
\node[process, right=of dec1] (pro4a) {Process 4a};
\node[process, right=of dec2] (pro7a) {Process 7a};
%
\node[connector, below=12mm of pro7b,
      label=right: continue on next page];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Flowchart}
    \end{figure}
\clearpage
    \begin{figure}[ht]\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
\caption{Flowchart (cont.)}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm and 8mm, % if needed
  start chain = going below, % if needed
                        ]
\node (con2) [connector, 
              label=right:continue];
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by line}]
\node[process,
      below=12mm of con2] (pro8) {unknown};
\node[process] (pro9) {unknown};
\node[process] (pro10) {unknown};
\node[process] (pro11) {unknown};
\node[startstop] (end) {Stop};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

**Addendum:**
For fun and exercise:

- different style for decision node
- use of `ext.paths.ortho` library for feedback loop(s)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin={3cm,=2cm},
            vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
        arrows.meta,        % arrow tips
        chains,             % start chain, on chain
        ext.paths.ortho,    % -|- and |-| path operations
        positioning,        % ...=of <node>
        shapes,             % signal, 
        shapes.geometric    % diamond, trapeziumchamfered rectangle
                }
\tikzset{
      arr/.style = {semithick,-Stealth},
     base/.style = {draw=#1, semithick, fill=#1!25,
                    text width=30mm, minimum height=11mm, align=center,
                    font=\sffamily,
                    on chain=A
                    },
       be/.style = {% BeginEnd
                    base=red, rounded corners},
            D/.style = {diamond, draw=#1, fill=#1!50, inner sep=2mm, anchor=center},
       if/.style = {base=teal, align=left,
                    label={[D=teal]north east:}},
          lbl/.style = {inner ysep=2pt, font=\small, text=black!75}, % for labels No, Yes
           lb/.style = {label={[lbl, anchor=north west]south:#1}},   % below
           ll/.style = {label={[lbl, anchor=south east]west:#1}},    % left
           lr/.style = {label={[lbl, anchor=south west]east:#1}},    % right
       io/.style = {% InputOutput
                    base=cyan,
                    trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110},
       pc/.style = {% ProCess
                    base=orange},
%
every chain label/.style={inner sep=1mm, font=\footnotesize},
off chain/.code={\def\tikz@lib@on@chain{}}          % <== defined interruption of chain
} % end of tikzset

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   node distance = 6mm and 12mm,
     start chain = A going below,
                    ]
% nodes
\node[be]   {Start};            % A-1
\node[io]   {Input};
\node[pc]   {Process 1};
\node[pc]   {Process 2};
\node[pc]   {Process 3};
\node[if,
      lb=False,
      lr=True]  {Decision 1};   % A-6
\node[pc]   {Process 4a};       % A-7
\node[pc]   {Process 5};
\node[pc]   {Process 6};
\node[if,
      lb=False,
      lr=True]  {Decision 2};   % A-10
\node[pc]   {Process 7a};
\node[io]   {New,\\ unknown action};  % A-12
\node[base=white]   {Continue on next page};  % A-13
%  off chain nodes
    \begin{scope}[nodes={pc, off chain}]  
\node[right=of A-7]  {Process 4b};  % A-14
\node[right=of A-11] {Process 7b};  % A-15
    \end{scope}
%%% arrows in main branch
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {1,2,...,12}
\draw[arr]  (A-\i) -- (A-\j);
%%%% arrows on the right
\draw[arr]  (A-6)   -|  (A-14);
\draw[arr]  (A-14)  |-  (A-8);
%
\draw[arr]  (A-10)   -|  (A-15);
\draw[arr]  (A-15)  |-  (A-12);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Flowchart}
    \end{figure}
\clearpage
    \begin{figure}[ht]\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
\caption{Flowchart (cont.)}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm and 8mm, % if needed
  start chain = A going below, % if needed
                        ]
\node[base=white]   {continue from\\previous page};
\node[pc]   {unknown proces};   % A-2
\node[pc]   {unknown action};
\node[pc]   {unknown action};
\node[if,
      lb=True,
      lr=False]  {If:\\
                  iteration \textgreater\ 100\\
                  \&    \\
                  tolerance \textless\  0.1};   % A-4
\node[io]   {Collected results};
\node[be]   {Stop};
%%% arrows in main branch
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {1,...,6}
\draw[arr]  (A-\i) -- (A-\j);
%%%% arrows on the right
\draw[arr]  (A-5) -|-[distance=12mm] (A-3.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One page

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,top=2cm}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, shapes.multipart,positioning}

\tikzset{
    startstop/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=3cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm}, process/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=3cm, text centered, minimum height=1cm}, decision/.style = {diamond, draw, text badly centered}, connector/.style={shape=signal, draw, signal to=south,text width=1cm,text height=1cm, align=center}, line/.style = {draw, -latex'}, input/.style = {trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, draw, text width=3cm, text centered, minimum height=1cm}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture} [node distance=0.5cm,]
        
        \node[startstop] (start) {Start};
        
        \node[input, below= of start] (in1) {Input};
        
        \node[process, below= of in1] (pro1) {Process 1};
        
        \node[process, below= of pro1] (pro2) {Process 2};
        
        \node[process, below= of pro2] (pro3) {Process 3};
        
        \node[decision,below= of pro3, yshift=-0.5cm] (dec1) {Decision 1};
        
        \node[process, right= of dec1, xshift=2cm] (pro4a) {Process 4a};
        
        \node[process, below= of dec1, yshift=-0.5cm] (pro4b) {Process 4b}; 
        
        \node[process, below= of pro4b] (pro5) {Process 5};
        
        \node[process, below= of pro5] (pro6) {Process 6};
        
        \node[decision, below= of pro6, yshift=-0.5cm] (dec2) {Decision 2};
        
        \node[process, right= of dec2, xshift=2cm] (pro7a) {Process 7a};
        
        \node[process, below= of dec2, yshift=-0.5cm] (pro7b) {Process 7b};
        
        \node[connector, below= of pro7b, yshift=-0.5cm] (con1) {};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Or lateral positioning

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,top=2cm}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, shapes.multipart,positioning}

\tikzset{
    startstop/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=3cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm}, process/.style = {rectangle, draw, text width=3cm, text centered, minimum height=1cm}, decision/.style = {diamond, draw, text badly centered}, connector/.style={shape=signal, draw, signal to=south,text width=1cm,text height=1cm, align=center}, line/.style = {draw, -latex'}, input/.style = {trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, draw, text width=3cm, text centered, minimum height=1cm}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture} [node distance=1cm]
        
        \node[startstop] (start) {Start};
        
        \node[input, below= of start] (in1) {Input};
        
        \node[process, below left=1cm and 2cm of in1] (pro1) {Process 1};
        
        \node[process, below=1cm of in1] (pro2) {Process 2};
        
        \node[process, below right=1cm and 2cm of in1] (pro3) {Process 3};
        
        \node[decision,below= of pro2, ] (dec1) {Decision 1};
        
        \node[process, right=of dec1] (pro4a) {Process 4a};
        
        \node[process, below left=1cm and 2cm of dec1] (pro4b) {Process 4b}; 
        
        \node[process, below= of dec1] (pro5) {Process 5};
        
        \node[process, below right=1cm and 2cm of dec1] (pro6) {Process 6};
        
        \node[decision, below= of pro5] (dec2) {Decision 2};
        
        \node[process, right=of dec2] (pro7a) {Process 7a};
        
        \node[process, below= of dec2, yshift=-0.5cm] (pro7b) {Process 7b};
        
        \node[connector, below= of pro7b, yshift=-0.5cm] (con1) {};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a way to let the flowchart go to the next page, instead of trying to keep everything in a slíngle page?

Comment: @VaradKulkarni, flowchart is image. If it is biger than one page, you need to break image in parts manually and insert each part separately.